# CeleryExecutor or LocalExecutor for periodic high volume and potentially long running tasks?

Tags: airflow

I have a workflow in Airflow that executes a large volume of tasks on several hosts my company runs (500+)

The workflow looks something like this:

1. Run a series of tests on a machine
2. Log results to database.  Results are per machine basis so results can be updated.
3. Publish a message to RabbitMQ (messages are picked up by various consumers)

The out of the box executor is very slow with respect for what I am doing.  I have tested out the CeleryExecutor (although setup was a bit of a pain), not at the volume that will be in production though.  I know with Celery I can distribute the tasks across multiple backends.

Is the CeleryExecutor more suited to what I am trying to do vs. the LocalExecutor?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely CeleryExecutor, with that you have spawn unlimited number of workers which can handle those many tasks.